# inserting into two tables from one sp

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm working on an sp that inserts data into two tables. The two tables are featured and featured type, both have a pk featuredid that gets auto incremented each time something is added. I have:

```
        insert into featured
        (title,text,imageURL, priority )
        values
        (@title,@text,@imageURL, @priority),

        insert into featuredtype
        (loginPage, indexPage, mobilePage)
        values
        (@loginPage, @indexPage, @mobilePage)
```

However, it appears this is not the correct method for inserting into two tables from one sp.

Comment: Change the comma separating your two statements to a semicolon.

Comment: Are you getting a syntax error?  It would be helpful to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get rid of the comma after `@priority),`

You can replace it with a semi-colon `;` or nothing at all, so

```
create proc yourproc
(
   -- parameter definitions here
)
as
begin
        insert into featured 
        (title,text,imageURL, priority ) 
        values 
        (@title,@text,@imageURL, @priority)

        insert into featuredtype 
        (loginPage, indexPage, mobilePage) 
        values 
        (@loginPage, @indexPage, @mobilePage) 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even try with

```
insert into featured (title,text,imageURL, priority ) 
select @title,@text,@imageURL, @priority

insert into featuredtype (loginPage, indexPage, mobilePage) 
select @loginPage, @indexPage, @mobilePage
```